# SQL CASE Statement - Return first match (ignore other matches)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple problem - I have two tables (table A and B) with records for staff members in each. A staff member may be reflected in both tables. I'm trying to put together a case statement that returns the first match for an employee from Table A and then exits the case statement (i.e., do not try to find that same employee in Table B). Right now, my current code returns matches from both Table A and Table B for that employee. How can I stop this?

Comment: `case expression` not statement :)

Comment: can you share what your current SQL Query looks like?

Comment: And sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
with AllStaff as
(
  select 1 as Level, StaffId, Name
  from TableA
  union all
  select 2 as Level, StaffId, Name
  from TableB
),
DistinctStaff as
(
    select distinct StaffId from AllStaff
)
select s.StaffId, sRec.*
from DistinctStaff as s
   outer apply 
     (select top(1) * from AllStaff as a where a.StaffId = s.StaffId order by a.Level) as sRec
group by s.StaffId
```